# OleDbException no es una ruta de acceso válida

Tags: c#

Holas.

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente: Estoy creando una aplicación web que se conecta a unas tablas de Visual FOX con la ayuda del proveedor **Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0.** Todo bien desde el *Visual Studio*, puedo consultar las tablas Fox, sin embargo cuando lo publico, en producción, me sale el siguiente errror:

> **'G:\rutafox\TABLAS\' no es una ruta de acceso válida. Asegúrese de que la ruta está escrita correctamente y que está conectado al
>   servidor donde se encuentra el archivo.**

He encontrado muchas soluciones a este problema, pero ninguna que solucione mi problema en particular.

Probé cambiar el nombre de mi ruta a las tablas `(G:\rutafox\TABLAS\, G:\rutafox\TABLAS, G:\\rutafox\TABLAS, etc.)` y sin éxito aún.

Mi cadena de conexión que lo jalo desde el **web.config** es la siguiente:

```
<add name="cnx" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source='G:\\rutafox\\TABLAS\\'; Extended Properties=dBase IV;" providerName="Microsoft.Jet.OleDb"/>
```

Ojo que con esos mismos datos y sobre la misma PC me funciona emulando a nivel de *Visual Studio*, el error me sale en la publicación de mi proyecto. Y para que tengan en cuenta, las tablas FOX a las que me conecto se encuentra remotas en un servidor al cual mapeo en una unidad de red sobre mi PC (G:). Si apunto a las mismas Tablas FOX pero copiadas a mi PC, no tengo ese error, es decir el problema está en remoto.

Agradecería mucho cualquier ayuda al respecto.

Comment: En donde se aloja la solución de tu proyecto y en donde se aloja la publicación de tu proyecto ?

Comment: Prueba escribiendo el atributo remote asi ->`connectionString= "Remote Provider =......"` en vez de solo `Provider` a ver que pasa

Comment: Gracias Martin por tu comentario.
Tanto la solución de mi proyecto como la publicación del mismo se encuentran ambas sobre mi propia PC y estoy consultando datos de unas tablas FOX que se encuentran en un servidor dentro de mi red.

Comment: Cuando solo cambio Provider por Remote Provider, me sale el siguiente mensaje:
No se ha especificado un proveedor OLE DB en ConnectionString.  Un ejemplo sería, 'Provider=SQLOLEDB;'.
He estado probando eso de las conexiones remotas, pero no encuentro una cadena de conexión exacta de guía como para mi ejemplo que se conecta a tablas FOX.

Comment: Estuve buscando temas parecidos y encontre esta :connectionString : "Provider=MS Remote;Remote
Server=http://myintranetserver/;Remote Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.
4.0;Data Source=c:\pass\be\quiz.mdb;uid=;Password=;" La verdad no entiendo donde radica el error y porque te anda a nivel solucion pero no a nivel producto final, me quede sin ideas. Espero que esto ultimo lo solucione

Comment: Había visto esa cadena de conexión para remoto, creo que funciona con archivos Excel o Access pero para FOX no, porque me sale el mensaje de error: No se puede crear el objeto de negocios.